# Is there any issue OR is it normal with this warning it comes with every pip command

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Is there any issue OR is it normal with this warning it comes with every pip command

Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behavior with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Answer (score 1):

This warning means that you are running `pip` as the root user of your system.

Since the root user has full control system-wide, this is not a recommended practice, as you are basically just executing random code (i.e. `setup.py` files) from the internet which can now do whatever it wants to your system.

Instead, you should run the `pip` command as another regular user with lesser permissions, to ensure the security of your system.

Comment: Additionally, systems like Linux use the root's python to run key OS programs. Therefore, installing packages into the root's environment could conflict with your underlying operating system. Also, the user may not have permissions to properly interact with root-owned files and folders.